# Why am I required to borrow while using a `match`?

Tags: rust

I am struggling to understand the principles behind borrowing while creating a simple program. This is what I have

```
pub struct GameBoard {
    p1_icon: String,
    p2_icon: String,
    current_player: i8,
}

impl GameBoard {
    pub fn prompt_turn(&self) {
        let misc = String::from("?");
        let icon = match self.current_player {
            1 => &self.p1_icon,
            2 => &self.p2_icon,
            _ => &misc,
        };
        println!(
            "It is Player {}'s turn to go. Please pick your next move to drop a {}",
            self.current_player, icon
        );
        println!("This is a test: {}", self.p1_icon)
    }
}
```

My primary question here is, why does Rust require me to borrow with `&self.p1_icon` within the `match` call, but not when I call `println`?

My next question is, I am having challenges working with string literals in Rust. In my case, there are some strings that are meant to be dynamic—thus why I use `String`s—but there are others that are just hard-coded (see `misc`).

It feels a bit overkill to create a `String`, then borrow from said `String`, so I can satisfy the constraints that "match values must all be `&String`". Is this really how Rust expects developers to code this way, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My primary question here is, why does Rust require me to borrow with `&self.p1_icon` within the `match` call, but not when I call `println`?

`println!` is a macro, not a regular function call, which allows it to bend the rules. When `println!` is expanded it inserts hidden `&` operators to borrow its arguments.

Running [`cargo expand`](https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand) to expand macros shows that the two `println!`s expand to:

```rust
{
    ::std::io::_print(
        ::core::fmt::Arguments::new_v1(
            &[
                "It is Player ",
                "\'s turn to go. Please pick your next move to drop a ",
                "\n",
            ],
            &[
                ::core::fmt::ArgumentV1::new_display(&self.current_player),
//                                                   ^-- added borrow
                ::core::fmt::ArgumentV1::new_display(&icon),
//                                                   ^-- added borrow
            ],
        ),
    );
};
{
    ::std::io::_print(
        ::core::fmt::Arguments::new_v1(
            &["This is a test: ", "\n"],
            &[::core::fmt::ArgumentV1::new_display(&self.p1_icon)],
//                                                 ^-- added borrow
        ),
    );
}
```

Notice how `&self.current_player`, `&icon`, and `&self.p1_icon` are all automatically borrowed.

I don't know if I like how `println!` does this. It makes it easier to type print statements, but in the process it muddles the borrowing story for new Rustaceans. Rust usually tries to avoid such surprises.

---

> It feels a bit overkill to create a `String`, then borrow from said `String`, so I can satisfy the constraints that "match values must all be `&String`". Is this really how Rust expects developers to code this way, or am I missing something?

You're right, it's overkill. There's no need for `misc` to be a heap-allocated `String`. You can make it a plain `&str` and it'll compile fine.

```rust
let misc = "?";
let icon = match self.current_player {
    1 => &self.p1_icon,
    2 => &self.p2_icon,
    _ => misc,
};
```

If you're wondering why this compiles when the match arms have different types (`&String` and `&str`), it's thanks to [type coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html) (warning: advanced read).

Rust tries to find a common type for the match arms. Using its [least upper bound coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#least-upper-bound-coercions) process, the compiler figures out that the result of the `match` block should be `&str`, and that it should coerce the two `&String` arms into `&str`. Such coercion is possible because of the general rule that coercion is allowed from "`&T` or `&mut T` to `&U` if `T` implements `Deref<Target = U>`", which applies since [`String` implements `Deref<Target = str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Deref).

In other words, it automatically inserts dereferences as if the `match` block had been written:

```
let misc = "?";
let icon = match self.current_player {
    1 => &*self.p1_icon,
    2 => &*self.p2_icon,
    _ => misc,
};
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly: in the main case where I want to just read a value and not change the owning variable, borrowing is how it's done. Some Rust macros will *not* require a `&` but will borrow under the hood.